# Tilde Expansion Doesn't Work in Docker COPY Command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tilde-expansion

I have a Dockerfile with the following line:

```
COPY *.zip ~user1
```

The user `user1` already exists and has a home directory (i.e. `/home/user1`). The goal, of course, is to copy the zip file into that user's home dir, however the result of the above is that the zip file is copied to a file named literally `/~user1` in the image.

The following does work as expected:

```
COPY *.zip /home/user1
```

Is this a bug in Docker or is there a **limitation related to tilde expansion** that I'm not aware of?

Using Docker 1.13.0 on Mac.

Comment: Tilde expansion is a feature of various unix/linux shells. The copy command is not processed by any of these shells.

Comment: It's not even working if you use tilde reference for your user directory with the docker compose commnad. See: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/8538

Answer (score 20):

Tilde expansion for `COPY` is not supported.

From [The COPY docs](http://docs-stage.docker.com/v1.10/engine/reference/builder/#copy):

> The `dest` is **an absolute path**, or a path relative to WORKDIR, into which the source will be copied inside the destination container.

Example:

```
COPY test relativeDir/   # adds "test" to `WORKDIR`/relativeDir/
COPY test /absoluteDir/  # adds "test" to /absoluteDir/
```

Comment: They should probably have a "Known Issues" section for this. Seems like a common issue.